# Using msg_send() in PHP results in error 11... Cannot find a solution

Tags: php, message-queue

I am currently building a small application that uses the message queue built in PHP.
I have 1 "server" process and 1 "client" process. Messages flow from server to client.

They are simple JSON objects, that are serialised, then send.

This code is used

```
<?php
$send = msg_send($q, MESSAGE_TYPE_EXECUTION, $update, true, false, $error);

if (isset($error) && $error != 0) {
    echo 'Execution error: ' . $error . PHP_EOL;
}

// $q is the message queue integer
// MESSAGE_TYPE_EXECUTION is integer 1
// $update is the JSON string
// true is that the JSON string is serialised
// false is that it is blocking (which it is not)
// $error get's filled when an error occurs (see below)
```

This works without issue, until it does not.
Sometimes after a couple of minutes, sometimes after a couple of hours the following error appears:

```
PHP Warning:  msg_send(): msgsnd failed: Resource temporarily unavailable in 
/var/www/server.php on line 57
```

The value of the `$error` variable is the integer 11.
All messages that follow this error will have error 11, until I restart the process and all is working again (for a while, until the same error appears again)

I have been searching but cannot find any explanation what error 11 is, how this can be managed and fixed without restarting the process.

Any clue, information, example etc is welcome. I would really like for server.php to be reliable.

-- edit --
client.php is the process that fetches the messages (which are all more or less the same, but with other values)

it uses this fetch the messages from the queue (filled in server.php)

```
<?php
$update = msg_receive($q, 0, $messagetype, 1024, $message, true, MSG_IPC_NOWAIT && MSG_NOERROR, $error);

if ($update) {
    // Do stuff
}
usleep(1000000);
```

I have not yet checked memory usage, will look into that

**Platform used**

- PHP 7.1.3
- Centos 7

Comment: I'm assuming you are also removing items from the queue, too, right? Do you notice a continual increase in memory?

Comment: Good question, I have edited the main question with how the messages are fetched by client.php

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting some messages larger than 1024 and those are piling up? Is there an `else` to the `if ($update) {`?

Comment: there is no else after if ($update)

But update is only true when there is a message, so the else would fire every time when there is no new message... 

Messages bigger than 1024 could be, but it also happens when it was 10240... And that caused the same, seemingly random, error 11

Comment: In your client you are using `MSG_IPC_NOWAIT && MSG_NOERROR`, but according to the documentation I think it should be `MSG_IPC_NOWAIT | MSG_NOERROR`. The `&&` is logical AND, which in this case is `true` which gets cast to `1` which is only `MSG_IPC_NOWAIT`, and you want boolean OR which is just a single `|`. I don't know if that affects your outcome in anyway, however

Comment: Ok, that is indeed something I missed, will change that. but that still is on the "reading" side of the application. The error only occurs in the "sending" side. 

It is the send_msg() call that returns this error. An error code that is not explained, so have no clue why or what it is caused by...

Comment: I'm just wondering if your queue is actually filling up. I unfortunately don't know a lot about this specific queue system, but I'm pretty certain that `11` is `EAGAIN`. The function you are using is a wrapper around [`msgsnd`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd) which says "If insufficient space is available in the queue, then the default behavior of msgsnd() is to block until space becomes available. If `IPC_NOWAIT` is specified in msgflg, then the call instead fails with the error `EAGAIN`" which is what appears to be happening.

Comment: That last bit is VERY interesting! I will look into this tomorrow, as I will be back on it again. Monitoring the queue length. I also believe it should be possible to increase the "queue size".

I will also speed up reading out the messages from the queue, as that would have it fill up less fast. Man, if that is the case, you are a true hero!

Comment: Did some digging with that and there is a command like below to show how many messages are in the queue... It is indeed a wrapper for msgsnd!

# ipcs -q

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    
0x00000045 0          root       666        16197        24          
0x00000002 1          root       666        2489         6           
0x00000001 2          root       666        2762         4           
0x00000046 3          root       666        0            0

Comment: Next day: I noticed I had a usleep() in the client.php file, that had a delay of 1.000.000 (which should have been 100.000) and I think that caused the client to be too slow. And the queue filled up during bursts of new messages. (which do happen)

Monitoring the queue length with the command ipcs -q in the console and all remains at zero now (after lowering the usleep timeout to 10.000)

Keep it running for as long as I can today to see if something else pops up, but @ChrisHaas, you helped me big time with your comments and knowledge! Much respect and thanks!

Comment: Awesome @MrG, glad I could help! Do you think you could write up an answer for this and self-accept it? I think this is a very niche problem but I bet someone would be glad for it eventually.

Comment: Will do for sure! Sad I cannot give you credit this way though... But I hope my thanks will be enough :) (Stackoverflow should have a BTC Lightning tip option... that would be killer...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Solution was found after some information and leads (read the comments on my original question), brought up by @ChrisHaas (Thanks again!). After some tinkering all is running smoothly now, without error 11 for msg_send().

PHP msg_send() call is basically a wrapper of [msgsnd](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd)
So a lot of information can be found there, also about errors you might encounter (in combination with flags used when reading messages with msg_receive() )

The queue is limited in total size and total messages it can hold (I, however, have not found a way to increase the total size of the queue).

The reason I was getting error 11 was due to a couple of things:

- The client I created was too slow fetching messages from the queue, causing it to run into the max limit and crapping out. I did not find a solution for fixing this situation, other than restarting all processes involved. To repeat the same over and over again.
- I also increased the size of reading messages in msg_receive() as sometimes the messages where big (most where small). But when you declare a too small size the big messages will remain in queue and clog it up until it craps out. Increasing the max_size helped with fetching the bigger messages too.

Long story short: error 11 is related to a full message queue in my perspective (I still do not have a 100% clear documented answer though).

Pointers to fix the issue:

- Be sure you fetch all messages that are big.
- Be sure to read out at least as fast as you send the messages in the queue.
- Check your queue(s) with the command ipcs -q in the terminal. It allows you to see the queues currently active. Keeping an eye on that allows you to see it slowly filling up on problems.

Wish the documentation on php.net was better in this case...